# Alternative to conditionals (if)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having difficulties with this task in python 3.7:

"Define a function that given two integers, a and b, returns the value of their sum. However, if the difference of a and b is an even number, the value of the sum is doubled, on the other hand, if the difference is an odd number, the value of the product of a and b gets added to the value of the sum.

For now, do not use conditionals (if)."

I don't know how to do it without using if statements. I would be thankful if anyone could help me.

If a=2 and b=2, the output should be 8.
If a=1 and b=4, the output should be 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine if the sum of the two integers is even, we use the modulo operator. The following will only evaluate to `0` or `1`: `(a - b) % 2`. `0` = even, `1` = odd.

Knowing this, we can use this value to index into a `list` which contains 2 functions.

At index `0` we have the `double` function, which will be called when the value is even, and at index `1` we have the `add_product` function, called when it's odd.

```
def process_numbers(a, b):
    def double(c):
        c *= 2
        return c

    def add_product(c):
        c += a * b
        return c

    functions = [double, add_product]

    c = a + b
    c = functions[(a - b) % 2](c)

    print(c)
    return c
```

Here is another solution using anonymous (lambda) functions, and taking advantage of the fact that `c & 1` will always evaluate to `0` if the difference between `a` and `b` is even, and `1` if it's odd.

```
def process_numbers(a, b):
    functions = (lambda: c*2, lambda: c + a*b)
    c = a + b
    return functions[c & 1]()
```

And a one-line monstrosity (avert your eyes!):

```py
>>> (lambda a, b: (lambda: (a + b) * 2, lambda: a + b + a * b)[a + b & 1]())(1, 4)
9
>>> (lambda a, b: (lambda: (a + b) * 2, lambda: a + b + a * b)[a + b & 1]())(2, 2)
8
```

It's a nice little puzzle. Where did you come across it?

---

Another solution, based off Demi-Lune's functionless solution.

```
>>> a, b = 2, 2
>>> (a + b & 1)*(a + b + a*b) + (1 - a + b & 1)*(a + b)*2
8
>>> a, b = 1, 4
>>> (a + b & 1)*(a + b + a*b) + (1 - a + b & 1)*(a + b)*2
9
```

If the sum of `a` and `b` is even, the left half evaluates to `0`, and the right half evaluates to the sum being doubled.

If the sum of `a` and `b` is odd, the right half evaluates to `0`, and the left half evaluates to the sum plus the product.

Comment: Thanks for the help, didn't know I could do this: 
   " functions = [double, add_product] " and then this:
   " c = functions[(a - b) % 2](c)  ". It is one of the exercises my teacher gave the class.

Comment: Nice one. I didn't know about this either. Guess, we all learn something new every day.

Comment: Yeah, functions are really flexible in Python. You can assign them to variables, add them to lists, tuples, dicts etc, pass them as arguments, and use them as return values.

Comment: This answer is brilliant, but the teacher might expect another answer, also using modulo : `((a-b+1)%2)*(a+b)*2 + (((a-b)%2)*(a+b)+a*b)`

Comment: Oh, nice idea! When a, b = 2, 2, it evaluates to 12, instead of 8. But I see what you're getting at.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. One more question: why does c & 1 evaluate to 0 if the difference between a and b is even, and 1 if it's odd ? I've never seen " & " being used in that context.

Comment: `&` is the *bitwise and* operator. It works on the bits that represent the numbers. Google it to find out more. Understanding how the binary number system works is needed to wrap your head around it. `any_number & 1` will clear all but the least significant bits in `any_number`, leaving you with either `1` or `0`. The least significant bit determines whether the number is even (`0`), or odd (`1`). If `a + b` (`c`) is even, then so will `a - b` (the difference between `a` and `b`). Try substituting different numbers for `a` and `b`. You'll see that's the case, no matter what.